# Design Pattern for Typescript library

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, singleton

I would like to develop a javascript/typescript library that work like this:

```js
import mylibrary from 'mylibrary'

mylibrary.config({
  token: 'myRandomString'
})

mylibrary.users.get({
  id: 'userIdString'
})

mylibrary.users.create({
  username: 'userName'
})

mylibrary.products.get({
  title: 'productTitle'
})

mylibrary.products.create({
  title: 'productTitle'
})
```

With `config()` function I will set all the data I need to make the library works. This just need to be done once.

Then inside `mylibrary` I have different objects with the almost the same methods, in the case above `users` and `products`.

I am trying to find the best way to implement this pattern in typescript. I don't want to instantiate a class. Is my pattern considered a Singleton?

How would you approach this pattern in typescript?

Is my library developed like this, a good idea?

```
const mylibrary:IMyLibray = {
  
  token: '',

  config(param:ConfigType){
    ...
  },

  users: {
    create(param:CreateTypeInput){
      ...
    }
  },

  ...
  
}
```

p.s.: I wanted to make a library like [Stripe](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js) that can be used in the browser and on the server.

Thank you

Comment: You certainly don't need to use a class and yes that's a singleton which is fine, but the problem with your design is that `myLibrary` can be used without or before configuring it. Consider having `config` return an object that provides access to functionality requiring configuration or just going with a library factory approach, allowing multiple objects to be created. You don't want a class, and you don't need a class!

Comment: I was thinking to throw an error if it is not configured. But I see the advantages of doing what you suggest. Right now I am thinking to wrote a Singleton for `mylibrary` and a singleton for each object like `users` and `products`. But isn't more clean to write the Singletons as classes? I thought that I would have more liberty if I was writing classes instead of objects. Am I wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Since I am developing in typescript, does it make any difference? Would you just use object? How can I use decorators then?

Comment: Not an iota of difference.